# ACF // Cannot display sub_fields from a repeater

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom taxonomy "collections". Collections items are available on the page via a relationship field.

I can access the collections and display the collections title. I'm also trying to display the data from a repeater but cannot find a way to access and display the repeater sub_fields.

When I do a var_dump($piecesList), I have an array showing the datas. How can I display these datas???

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$collections = get_field('collectionSelector'); /* relationship field */
if( $collections ):
foreach( $collections as $collections_post ):
    $piecesList = get_field( 'pieces', $collections_post->ID );

        if( $piecesList ):

        foreach( $piecesList as $piecesList_post ):
            $pieceName = get_field( 'piece_name', $piecesList_post->ID );
            echo $pieceName;

        endforeach;
        endif;

endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show var_dump($piecesList) please?

Comment: Well Paul thank you for your comment! As I was adding the var_dump in my code I noticed that I added "$collections_post->ID" when it should have been "$collections_post".